# How to hide notification when service is starts?

Tags: android

Is there any way to hide notification when service is starts ?

There is a lot apps uses service for API 26 and above without show any notification , How ?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("1", getResources().getResourceName(R.string.app_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(IncomingCallService.this, "1").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.text)).setShowWhen(false).build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
} else {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: "Is there any way to hide notification when service is starts ?" -- do not use `startForeground()`. Your service will need to complete its work in less than a minute on Android 8.0 and higher. "There is a lot apps uses service for API 26 and above without show any notification" -- please explain in detail how you have determined that these apps are using a continously-running background service, and not some other solution (FCM, `WorkManager`, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare Is  it impossible to hide notification ? How I can put when click on notification then show toast message ?

Comment: "Is it impossible to hide notification ?" -- I hope so, as otherwise there is a bug. Users have complained **very loudly** that they do not like apps continuously running in the background without their knowledge. That is why, three years ago, this change was made. "How I can put when click on notification then show toast message ?" -- ideally, you would do something better for the user than that. After all, you need an activity to allow the user to control the behavior of your background service. So, have your notification lead to that activity.

Comment: Anyway thanks , I'm looking move to use work manager is it good or no ?

Comment: If you have work that needs to be done every so often, particularly based on certain rules ("must have an Internet connection", "must be plugged into a charger", etc.), `WorkManager` seems fine.

Comment: No I want create broadcast for phone state listener in background , is it good with work manager ?

Comment: No, sorry, `WorkManager` is not suitable for a broadcast receiver. Use a foreground service, and live with the notification requirement.